# Making inventory with JQuery UI and moving icons

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

With the JQuery UI, I want to move the icons in the inventory one by one into the blue squares. When I drag the icons, they stay out of the squares. It is not put into squares.

I want only one icon in each frame. It should also be restored when dragging and dropping through the Squares.

Only icons should move.

Note: "Drag and drop to test."

Example: [image]

```js
    $(".account-list div, .inventory-list div").sortable({
        placeholder: "",
        connectWith: ".account-list > div, .inventory-list > div",
        containment: "body",
        revert: true,
        opacity: 0.8,
        zIndex: 9999,
        cursor: "move",
        scroll: false,
        create: function(event, ui) {
            
        },
        start: function(event, ui) {

        },
        create: function(event, ui) {

        },
        update: function(event, ui) {

        }
    }).disableSelection();
```

```css
body,html{
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    .card {
        width: 260px;
        height: 300px;
        display: inline-grid;
        border: 4px solid rgb(8 208 255);
        background: #ffffff;
        position: relative;
        color: rgb(8 208 255);
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .card-title{
        padding: 10px;
        border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(8 208 255);
    }
    .icon {
        background: url(https://svgur.com/i/NVE.svg) center center no-repeat;
        background-size: 40px;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        flex: 1 0 27%;
    }

    .inventory-list{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .account-list{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .slot{
    flex: 1 0 27%;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(240 253 255);
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    border: 2px solid #59dfff;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<div class="card">
    <div class="card-title">Inventory</div>
   <div class="inventory-list">
        <div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div><div class="slot"><div class="icon"></div></div>    </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-title">Account</div>
    <div class="account-list">
        <div class="slot"></div>
        <div class="slot"></div>
        <div class="slot"></div>
        <div class="slot"></div>
        <div class="slot"></div>
        <div class="slot"></div>
        <div class="slot"></div>
        <div class="slot"></div>
        <div class="slot"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do items in the Inventory need to be sorted? Or is the User just grabbing an item from that to drag into the Account list?

Comment: @Twisty The ranking of products in inventory does not matter much. Items in the inventory and items in the Account Section can be moved to each other. It can carry to both sides.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so it makes sense to have both be Sortable, so items can be moved back and forth. The order in Inventory is not of importance, just the placement in Account list, right?

Comment: @Twisty yes....

Answer (score 1):

The basic crux of the issue is that you have two sortable lists and when you move an item from one to the other, you want it to be appended inside the container, not to the list itself.

To resolve this, you can do a few things, I would advise making the target a droppable that can then accept the item, append it, and still retain it's sortable ability.

Consider the following basic yet not complete example.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".inventory-list").sortable({
    placeholder: "",
    containment: "body",
    opacity: 0.8,
    zIndex: 9999,
    cursor: "move",
    scroll: false
  });
  $(".account-list").sortable({
    placeholder: "",
    connectWith: ".inventory-list",
    containment: "parent",
    revert: true,
    opacity: 0.8,
    zIndex: 9999,
    cursor: "move",
    scroll: false,
    handle: ".sort-handle"
  });
  $(".slot").droppable({
    accept: ".icon",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      $("<span>", {
        class: "sort-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se"
      }).appendTo(this);
      $(this).append(ui.draggable.clone().attr("style", "").removeClass("ui-sortable-handle ui-sortable-helper")).droppable("disable");
      ui.draggable.remove();
      $(".icon", this).draggable({
        connectWithSortable: ".inventory-list",
        revert: true,
        opacity: 0.8,
        zIndex: 9999,
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.card {
  width: 260px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-grid;
  border: 4px solid rgb(8 208 255);
  background: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  color: rgb(8 208 255);
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.card-title {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(8 208 255);
}

.icon {
  background: url(https://svgur.com/i/NVE.svg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  flex: 1 0 27%;
}

.inventory-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.account-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.slot {
  flex: 1 0 27%;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(240 253 255);
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  border: 2px solid #59dfff;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  display: flex;
  /*align-items: center;*/
}

span.sort-handle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  align-self: start;
  margin-top: 0;
  cursor: "move";
}

.slot .icon {
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-title">Inventory</div>
  <div class="inventory-list">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-title">Account</div>
  <div class="account-list">
    <div class="slot"></div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Based on your description, this does everything you want, yet I suspect you did not outline all the things needed. This allows the User to drag an item from Inventory and add it to an Account container. Both Inventory and Accounts can be sorted and even have an Account dragged back to Inventory (almost). I suspect you can already see the further work that has to be done.

You might consider making Inventory just a Draggable group of items that can be dragged into Droppable containers. Those containers can be sorted. I would add buttons, like a revert button to return it to the Inventory list without having to drag it so there is less complexity. The User will not move it to another container, but just sort the containers as needed.

Comment: By doing a small edit in my codes, I solved most of the problem. Problem Multiple icons are added in 1 box. If I prevent this, the problem will be solved.  https://streamable.com/2cpe7r

Comment: @AlexDenial I see the new code. Basically making each DIV a single item list. So now the challenge is to only accept an item when the list is empty. I suspect this will be something done in the `over` event.

Answer (score 0):

**I did not sleep all night and tried to do this for 13 hours and finally I succeeded.**

```js
var invalid = false;
   $(".inventory-list div, .account-list div").sortable({
       placeholder: " ",
       connectWith: ".inventory-list div, .account-list div",
       containment: ".container",
       opacity: 0.7,
       zIndex: 9999,
       cursor: "pointer",
       scroll: false,
       create: function( event, ui ) {
           if ( !$(this).is(':empty') ){
               $(this).addClass("item-disabled");
           }
       },
       over: function( event, ui ) {
           if( this !== event.currentTarget ){
               if($(event.target).hasClass("item-disabled")   ){
                   invalid = true;
               }
           }
       },
       over: function(event,ui){
          invalid = false;
           if( this !== event.currentTarget ){
               if( $(event.target).hasClass("item-disabled") ){
                 invalid = true;
               }
           }
       },
       remove: function( event, ui ) {
           if(invalid != true){
               $(this).removeClass("item-disabled");
           }
       },
       receive: function( event, ui ) {
           if(invalid == true){
               ui.sender.sortable("cancel");
           }
           $(this).addClass("item-disabled");
       }
   });
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    body{
        background: #f5f5f5;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    .card {
        width: 260px;
        display: inline-grid;
        border: 2.5px solid rgb(8 208 255);
        background: #ffffff;
        position: relative;
        color: rgb(8 208 255);
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .card-title{
        padding: 10px;
        border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(8 208 255);
        background: #08d0ff;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .icon {
        background-size: 60px;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: flex;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        flex: 1 0 27%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .c1{
        background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/927/927593.svg');
    }
    .c2{
        background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/859/859205.svg');
    }
    .c3{
        background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148919.svg');
    }
    .c4{
        background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148838.svg');
    }
    .c5{
        background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/138/138292.svg');
    }
    .c6{
        background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148808.svg');
    }


    .inventory-list{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .account-list{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .account-list, .inventory-list{
        min-height: 315px;
        background-color: rgb(240 253 255);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .slot{
        flex: 1 0 27%;
        margin: 5px;
        height: 65px;
        width: 65px;
        border: 2px solid #59dfff;
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background: white;
    }
    .container{
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Inventory System</title>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#08d0ff" />
    <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#08d0ff" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#08d0ff" />
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-title">Inventory</div>
        <div class="inventory-list">
            <div class="slot"><span class="icon c1"></span></div>
            <div class="slot"><span class="icon c2"></span></div>
            <div class="slot"><span class="icon c3"></span></div>
            <div class="slot"><span class="icon c4"></span></div>
            <div class="slot"><span class="icon c5"></span></div>
            <div class="slot"><span class="icon c6"></span></div>
             <div class="slot"></div>
              <div class="slot"></div>
 <div class="slot"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-title">Account</div>
        <div class="account-list">
          <div class="slot"></div>
          <div class="slot"></div>
          <div class="slot"></div>
          <div class="slot"></div>
          <div class="slot"></div>
          <div class="slot"></div>
           <div class="slot"></div>
            <div class="slot"></div>
             <div class="slot"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```